Additional graph not showing on plot
I have tried different functions to make my "test_mse" show on my plot. But it does not. I do not get any errors as well. p is a value = 10 , train_mse and test_mse are vectors with values. Below is the code:
plot(1:p, train_mse, type = "b", pch = 19, col = "blue", 
     xlab = "Number of Components (M)", ylab = "Mean Squared Error (MSE)",
     main = "PCR: Training and Test MSEs vs. Number of Components")

# Add test MSEs to the plot
points(1:p, test_mse, type = "b", pch = 19, col = "red", add = TRUE)

# Add legend
legend("topright", legend = c("Training MSE", "Test MSE"), col = c("blue", "red"), pch = 19, cex = 0.8)


Try ylim <- range(c(train_mse, test_mse)); plot(1:p, train_mse, ylim = ylim, etc). Like this the y axis will cover all points, not just the points drawn in the first graphic instruction, plot.

Or ymax <- max(c(train_mse, test_mse)); plot(1:p, train_mse, ylim = c(0, ymax), etc).

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.
